# Steps involved in configuring SQL Server and its components after server is renamed

Tags: sql-server, configuration, ssrs

I have a cloned (duplicate) server with SQL Server on it and the server name had to obviously change once it was copied. This [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/rename-a-computer-that-hosts-a-stand-alone-instance-of-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) describes two actions to perform:

1. using below code to manually rename SQL Server:

   ```
   sp_dropserver <old_name>;  
   GO  
   sp_addserver <new_name>, local;  
   GO
   ```
2. [some changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/rename-a-report-server-computer?view=sql-server-2017) in SSRS.

***My questions are:***

- are there other things I need to consider/change?
- Despite following all of those items, I still get the following issue: 
  in SSRS Configuration Manager, under Scale-out Deployment, I still have a reference to the old server.
- Isn't that article incomplete given it does not speak of SSAS, SSIS, and  Linked servers?

**Assumptions**:

- SQL Server in question has just one instance (default)
- There exists no mirroring, failover cluster, replication, etc. It's a simple case.

Answer (score 1):

You've noted that your setup doesn't use mirroring, failover clustering, replication, etc, so it sounds like you've done everything you need to do inside SQL Server.  If you are changing the name of the this server as part of replacing an old decommissioned server, you'll need to ensure the logins from the old server are configured in the new server to ensure clients will be able to connect.

As for Reporting Services, aside from altering the Database settings, you'll also need to change the name of the Report Server URL in the `<UrlString>` node of the RsReportServer.config in `%SystemRoot%\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\<SSRSInstanceName>\Reporting Services\ReportServer`.  Ensure the UrlString points to the correct name of the server, then restart the SSRS service.

You'll need to change the Report Server Database to refer to the new name of the SQL Server machine:

[image]

It's not clear what the actual problem is regarding your scale-out deployment.  Perhaps a screenshot of the problem screen might help explain what you're seeing.